# Cross phone mobile video recommend

Tags: video, mobile

Ok guys, I'm looking for a solution to play a video once a user scans a qr code. everything works, even the player but i'm looking for a way so that the video either starts right when you get to the screen or atleast gives you a good visual and tells you to hit play. I'm running into so many issues with compatibility on different phones. It looks good on iphone but not android etc... any ideas on solutions? would HTML5 work on all the major players? jwplayer just doesnt seem to cut it.

Answer (score 0):

html5 should work on wp7, ios, android, hp/palm and blackbery OS 7.1 (that's brand new so not a lot of users yet)

so try that yes :)